# Как задать высоту блока исходя от высоты в нем фона через css?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Задача, отобразить фоновую картинку в полную высоту учитывая также адаптивность.

Задать `height` для `div` не получится, так как используется `background-size: cover`

```css
div {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Small_Red_Rose.JPG/320px-Small_Red_Rose.JPG);
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 320px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span>Просто текст</span>
```

Буду очень рад варианту решения без JS

Comment: В полную высоту чего? текста? экрана? страницы?

Comment: @kizoso, видимо, в полную высоту фоновой картинки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете отказаться от использования background, а сымитировать фон, вставив картинку в html и задав ей position: absolute. Тогда её высота будет всегда адаптироваться в соответствии с изменением ширины и при этом сама картинка будет полностью отображаться.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 320px;
  width: 100%;
}
.fon {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .5;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  padding: 35px 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1336853/75c03624-660f-4cce-8a3f-60dc04d87880/s1200" alt="" class="fon" />
<div class="inner"> Здесь какой-то текст или иное содержимое поверх фона</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
img{
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div><img src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Small_Red_Rose.JPG/320px-Small_Red_Rose.JPG /></div>
<span>Просто текст</span>
```